# Order query by special relation and paginate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a website that is listing different products on a page using Laravel pagination. The products on this page should be ordered by their name, however, here lies the problem.

The structure of my database looks like this:

```
+----------+    +--------------+
| Products |    | Translations |
+----------+    +--------------+
| Id       |    | product_id   |
| ...      |    | slug         |
+----------+    | locale       |
                | value        |
                +--------------+
```

The name of every product is available in the `translations` table where `slug='name'`. However, not every product has a translation in every available `locale`.
The name of the product should be the translation in the given locale. If this is not available, the English name is used. If this is not available either, the first available translation is used.

Is it somehow possible to do this in eloquent or MySQL? I have been looking for solutions but couldn't find one that did exactly this.

Comment: Where do you store the English name? or other names for that matter?

Comment: All names are stored in the translations table using the `product_id`, `slug` and `locale` to find the correct translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function, which returns the first non-null value such as:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(<sub-query by locale>, 
    <sub-query to bring english name>, 
    <sub-query to bring any other value you want>) FROM product;
```

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed fix my problem. :)